Choosing a category name in WordPress that I am on the archive page
I am designing the category.php and tag.php pages and I would like to use an element in these two pages that works like this:
This element should display the posts from the same category or tag that the user is in the archive page, in a number of 6, such that the number of comments accepted for them this week is not zero, in fact, it should have at least one comment so that posts for which no comments have been registered this week are not displayed here.
Now I have a few problems.
1/ I don't know how to write the WordPress loop in a way that it takes the content from the category that the user is in and not in general. In fact, I don't want the name or slug to be static as shown below and I want the slug or name to change depending on the category that the user is in:
'category_slug' => 'travel' no
'category_name' => 'travel' no

But something like this:
'category_name' => 'echo get_the_archive_title();'

2/ Also I am not sure if I have implemented something like: Last week's posts; with this code correctly or not, I would appreciate it if you could tell me if it is not correct:
                            'date_query' => array(
                            array(
                                // 'before' => '1 month ago',
                                'after' => '1 month ago',
                            ),
                        ),

Thank you very much to my friends who are helping me because I have been looking for a solution to this problem for almost hours!
You can see the loop code I wrote below:
<?php
                    $post_filter_by_most_comment = new WP_Query( array(
                        'category_name' => '???????????????',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                        'order' => 'desc',
                        'date_query' => array(
                            array(
                                // 'before' => '1 month ago',
                                'after' => '1 month ago',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));

                    if ($post_filter_by_most_comment->have_posts()) {
                        while ( $post_filter_by_most_comment->have_posts() ) : $post_filter_by_most_comment->the_post();
                            ?>

                            <div>

                                <!-- post photo -->
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <?php
                                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                                the_post_thumbnail('');  // add size in side ''
                                            }
                                            else{ ?> <img src=" <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/error.jpg'  ?> "> <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- photo for shadow -->
                                            <?php
                                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                                the_post_thumbnail('');  // add size in side ''
                                            }
                                            else{ ?> <img src=" <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/error.jpg'  ?> "> <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                                <!-- post content -->
                                <div>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                                    </a>
                                    <!-- tags -->
                                    <!--<a href="#">-->
                                    <!--    <h6>برچسب: زدواج و طلاق</h6>-->
                                    <!--</a>-->
                                    <?php the_tags('' , '' , ''); ?>
                                    <!-- author and post date -->
                                    <div>
                                        <a href=" <?php
                                        global $post;
                                        $author_id=$post->post_author;
                                        echo get_author_posts_url($author_id);
                                        ?> ">
                                            <h6>نویسنده: <?php the_author(); ?></h6>
                                        </a>
                                        <h6><?php the_time( 'j F Y' ); ?></h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        <?php
                        endwhile;
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>


I think you want to have a category/tag archive page that shows 6 things at a time, but only show items that have comments. Is that what the first paragraph is trying to say?
